# Sort imported HTML table

Tags: jquery, html, tablesorter

I have the following which populates my table:

```
if (jsonObj[0].array !== 'undefined' && jsonObj[0].array.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj[0].array.length; i++) {
        var table_row = "<tr><td>" + jsonObj[0].array[i].siteId + "</td>";

        var date = new Date(0); 
        date.setUTCSeconds(jsonObj[0].array[i].time);
        table_row = table_row + "<td>" + date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds() + "</td>";
        table_row = table_row + "<td>" + jsonObj[0].array[i].field1 + "</td>";
        table_row = table_row + "<td>" + jsonObj[0].array[i].field2 + "</td>";
        table_row = table_row + "<td>" + jsonObj[0].array[i].field3 + "</td>";
        table_row = table_row + "<td>" + jsonObj[0].array[i].field4 + "</td>";

        var totalCount = jsonObj[0].array[i].field1 + jsonObj[0].array[i].field2 + jsonObj[0].array[i].field3 + + jsonObj[0].array[i].field4;

        if (totalCount > 100) {
            table_row = table_row + totalCount + "</td></tr>";
        } else if (totalCount > 80){
            table_row = table_row + totalCount + "</td></tr>";
        } else {
            table_row = table_row + totalCount + "</td></tr>";
        }

        $("#my-table").find("#my-table-body").append(table_row);
    }
}
```

I have the following markup for the table in my .html file:

```
<table id="my-table" style="height:200px; width:1020px" class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Field 1 Title</th>
                    <th>Field 2 Title</th>
                    <th>Field 3 Title</th>
                    <th>Field 4 Title</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="my-table-body">
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

I want to make each column sortable. So when we select 'Field1 Title' on the table, it should call a function in my JavaScript which will sort the table. Can anyone help, I have tried TableSorter but it doesn't seem to work using this function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#my-table").tablesorter()
});
```

Comment: You should be able to initialize the tablesorter directly after you populate it, rather than on doc.ready. Also, destroy it before you populate it if it gets recreated at any point.

Comment: Hi, where do you recommend I initialize it from instead?

Comment: Destroy it before the loop, initialize after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (cleaned up so it only "touches" the DOM once):

```
if (jsonObj[0].array !== 'undefined' && jsonObj[0].array.length > 0) {
    var table_rows = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj[0].array.length; i++) {
        table_row += "<tr><td>" + jsonObj[0].array[i].siteId + "</td>";

        var date = new Date(0); 
        date.setUTCSeconds(jsonObj[0].array[i].time);
        table_row += "<td>" + date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds() + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + jsonObj[0].array[i].field1 + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + jsonObj[0].array[i].field2 + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + jsonObj[0].array[i].field3 + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + jsonObj[0].array[i].field4 + "</td>";

        var totalCount = jsonObj[0].array[i].field1 + jsonObj[0].array[i].field2 + jsonObj[0].array[i].field3 + + jsonObj[0].array[i].field4;

        /* I'm not sure what this is about
        if (totalCount > 100) {
            table_row = table_row + totalCount + "</td></tr>";
        } else if (totalCount > 80){
            table_row = table_row + totalCount + "</td></tr>";
        } else {
            table_row = table_row + totalCount + "</td></tr>";
        }
        but, the following does the same thing
        (and adds the missing opening "<td>"):
        */
        table_row += "<td>" + totalCount + "</td></tr>";

    }
    $("#my-table-body").append(table_row);
    $('#my-table').tablesorter();
}
```

If tablesorter is already initialzied, intead of re-initializing it, replace the last two lines with this:

```
$("#my-table-body").append(table_row);
$('#my-table').trigger('update');
```